# Keeps getting disconnected even when working on the 'Pi'

Tags: ssh

```
ssh : Write failed: Broken pipe.
```

I could understand it if the Pi was idle, but when I'm still working on it makes no sense. What could be the possible reason?

I ssh from mac os x, over a LAN connection.

Comment: what model Pi, distribution? and have you updated and upgraded and got the latest firmware?

Comment: B+, Raspbian , raspberrypi 3.12.35+.

Comment: Try `grep sshd /var/log/syslog` and see if there is anything about this there.

Comment: Just for the sake of the argument: What kind of power supply are you using?

Comment: ...and what kind of peripheral equipment do you have connected to the Pi? What where you working with when this happened?

Comment: 10w usb power adapter, for iOS devices. didn't have  problem till I started working on Flask api and apache2. have a breadboard and usb webcam connected to the pi.

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? Did you check the syslog?

Comment: Nothing in the syslog. brought a new adapter to check if the adapter was a problem, but the adapter not working,:) The other day was still giving me trouble. Weird thing is i can ssh again after some time -10, 15 min later without doing anything to pi.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the proper power adapter. A common charger for smartphones may also be used. You may refer https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs and http://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware_Basic_Setup#Power_Supply

Comment: While using a proper power adapter is generally a good idea, I don't understand what makes you think an improper one would be the problem in this particular case.

Comment: @Bex "proper" means according to the one advised in the link, i.e. a micro-USB, 5V, 2500mA power adapter.

Comment: @goldilocks But the TS explicitly states LAN connection.

Comment: @Bex Oh yeah...my bad.   I guess it still might be possible if it is seriously underpowered (<=500 mA) although I haven't heard of this particular problem.

Comment: I had the same problem which was ultimately resolved with a good quality power adapter. [This](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Networking) also can be referred.

Comment: @goldilocks Oh, it might very well be a problem with the power supply - it's just that nothing really indicates the power supply more clearly than a faulty LAN cable, a torn RJ45 connector, or disturbance from solar flares.

Comment: I don't think these was a problem with the power adapter. used the Pi only as a server for 2 days, and got disconnected just once and was able to ssh immediately.  Will be working on an Api again and will update these post if the problem persist. Thank you for your valuable feedback.